# How to stop Django from hanging after page refresh using channels?

Tags: python-3.x, django, websocket, channel, django-channels

Using channels it connects properly when the page loads the first time but then hangs on refresh. Not sure why this is happening. I've placed the code below to see what might be happening?

```html
# index.html
<script>
    let socket = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8001/ws/');
    socket.onmessage = () => {
        console.log("Connected");
    };
    socket.onclose = () => {
        console.log('Websocket closed');
    }
</script>
```

```py
# app/consumer.py
from json import dumps
from time import sleep

from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer

class WSConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()
        self.send(dumps({'message': 'connected'}))
        
        for i in range(1000):
            self.send(dumps({'message': i}))
            sleep(2)
```

```py
#app/routing.py
from django.urls import path
from app.consumers import WSConsumer

ws_urlpatterns = [
    path('ws/', WSConsumer.as_asgi())
]
```

```py
#core/asgi.py
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter
from channels.routing import URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

from app.routing import ws_urlpatterns

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "core.settings")
django.setup()

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": get_asgi_application(),
    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(URLRouter(ws_urlpatterns)),
})
```

```py
# core/urls.py
...
    path('test/', views.IndexView.as_view()),
...
```

In my settings I've added `channels` just below the `.sites` app but above everything else and I've added the `ASGI_APPLICATION` and running the application with `python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8001`